# SQL query to get all the rows from multiple tables even it has uneven primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql

I have multiple tables, like below

Table-1:

```
    ID | Name
----------------
     1 | John
     2 | Doe
     3 | Mark
     4 | Hill
     5 | Ram
```

Table-2:

```
    ID | place
----------------
     1 | CA
     2 | NY
     4 | AK
     5 | CT
```

Table-3:

```
    ID | age
----------------
     2 | 35
     3 | 23
     4 | 54
```

I need to get the output table as

Table-1:

```
    ID | Name   | Place   |  Age
-----------------------------------
     1 | John   | CA     | 
     2 | Doe    | NY     |  35
     3 | Mark   |        |  23 
     4 | Hill   | AK     |  54
     5 | Ram    | CT     |
```

I tried using `join` and `union`, however I could not find the solution. Could you please someone give me the solutions?

Comment: select from table1, left join others

Comment: can  you give me a query to get rows from multiple tables?

Comment: Can you have IDs in table3 that are not in table1? (or table2)

Comment: Foreign and primary keys are there to make sure data is consistent. No big purpose when doing a select.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join as below:

```
select t1.id, t1.name,t2.place, t3.age
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
left join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The result as shown can be obtained using an outer join:

```
select *
from table1 
  left join table2 using (id)
  left join table3 using (id);
```

The join through the `using` operator has the nice side effect that the ID column will only show up once in the result even though I have used `select *`

Your example doesn't show this, but if you have IDs in table2 that are *not* in table1 but you still want them in the result, you need to use a full outer join.

```
select *
from table1 
  full join table2 using (id)
  full join table3 using (id);
```

The `using (id)` know has another nice side effect: it will automatically use the ID value from whichever table the id came from without the need to use a `coalesce(id)` in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

select t1.id, name, place, age

from table1 t1

`  left outer join table2 on t1.id=t2.id

```
   left outer join table3 on t1.id=t3.id;
```